# A fairly small Excel sheet is getting an error on upload to google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

What are some of the reasons? Are there certain formulas not supported, for example? Any links would be appreciated.

Comment: 'An error' is pretty vague. Any pictures or description of the error would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right... There was no error message other than 'import error' and the excel file was complicated (but not especially big.) Anyway, I withdraw the question until I have a better question to ask!